# Signal differences into Labview to those measured before Multiplexer

Tags: atmega

First off, I'm not the programmer.  I am however trying to help him out with my limited knoweledge of IC's and Labview.  But I am reaching the limits of what I know so really need some help. ;)

We have (for example) a gas temperature signal coming into an OP, that is being increased by a factor of 30.  To increase it from the uV into mV.  It is a thermoucouple sensor.

This signal is passed on to a Multiplexer (HEF4051BP).

When attaching a K-Type simululator and measuring the incoming signal into the the Multiplexer, all is well...the signal is 1:1.  For example, by 20C the signal is 29.3mV (0.798mV x 30 through the OP).

Now, this signal gets passed (along with others connected to the Multiplexer) to a MAX110 A/D converter.  From here to an Atmega 168 to be read into Labview.  The Atmega also controls the Multiplexer switching signals and timing.

So, reading the incoming signals in Labview over the COM port from the Atmega, I see differences. The converted signal coming in does not match 1:1 with the signal going into the Multiplexer.  Accounting for error tolerance and all, it still is a large difference.  For example 0.0v in LabView shows as 0.003 and 0.760mV shows in Labview as 0.754mV(I forget the exact value).

This is a problemas we cannot linearise the incoming signals with the LabView K-Type scaling methods as the cuvre appears different to what is to be expected....If we took these signals directly before the multiplexer it would work as these follow the K-Type Industry Standard Table.

Fact is, we have used the OP, Multiplexer, MAX110 configuration many times before and have never had a problem.  So my guess is the Atmega controlling the show, is doing something it shouldn't.  As I know very lttle about the Atmega I thought I would as you guys for some ideas.

Any ideas?

Comment: The Atmega 168 has 6 (or 8 if SMD) analog inputs.  Can you get by with just 6 (or 8) inputs, or do you really need to use an external multiplexer?

Comment: Are you doing cold junction compensation and if so where - in the Atmega program or in LabVIEW? How are you measuring the intermediate signals to check if they're correct or not? If you take the multiplexer out of circuit and simply inject a test voltage at the ADC input, is that read correctly?

Comment: Thanks for the comments and ideas.   We are getting closer...seems to be a timing issue with the Multiplexer/Max110... I will post back when I know exactly. Basically reading the value too quickly so that only 90% of the Analogue signal is being retrieved...so the theory anyway..

Comment: Yes we need the multiplexer as the Atmega only receives positive signals...we also need negative.  CJC is done before the OP and is confirmed to work.

Answer (score 1):

This could well be due to the fact that your ADC is a Delta-Sigma and therefore looking for a varying signal and not a relatively static one from the thermocouple. I would bite the bullet and just buy the relevant DAQ device from NI. Once you have it it will take minutes to measure the signal. 
Or try getting a temperature sensor with built in converter that gives the output as I2C that means there will be little room for conversion error, as you will also have many dissimilar metal joins all adding an effect to your thermocouple signal.

Comment: The NI DAQ was tried, but for our purposes was not viable due to resolution problems and a few other glitches.  Not to mention the cost.